# Unexpected Token < ... cant find issue

Tags: javascript

I am getting an "unexpected token <" error with the following javascript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_menu(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

The only "<" that is used is to designate the javascript. I've checked stackoverflow, and see posts that suggest the following ... but none address my code specifically nor address the problem (so no, this is not a duplicate post)

1. changing the type from "text/javascript" to "text/html" ... but that just makes my script stop working.
2. I've also seen recommendations to add `<script><![CDATA[ /* Code here */ ]]></script>` ... but the CDATA info just made my script stop working again.
3. I've seen recommendations to remove excess ";" ... but that didn't do anything to fix the error.
4. Remove any comment tags (um... there are none)
5. Mixing up parenthesis (none that I see)

This is simple javascript, and I don't see where the error is coming from.

Some more clarification.

- The javascript is NOT in its own file. It is at the top of my page.
- There is no javascript above the code (or any js files being called before the code).
- Here is the content of the html tag (stack overflow wont let me type in the actually html tag ...

  ```
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US"
  ```
- Below is the html calling the toggle...

  ```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_menu('popup-1');"> Open Window </a>
  ```

(Note: The javascript WORKS, I just want to get rid of the error)

Comment: How are you calling `toggle_menu`? You should probably add the affected HTML too. I'd also suggest the use of curly braces in your if...else statement.

Comment: How are you including that script? If it's in its own file and you're including it with *another* `<script src="something.js">` tag, then that's the problem. `<script>` tags are only for HTML source - you don't use them in pure JavaScript files.

Comment: probably you've got some broken JS before this particular snippet? e.g,. `<script> var foo = 'bar'; <script> .... </script>`? e.g. you're putting a NEW `<script>` tag while already in a JS script block.

Comment: What does your <html> tag look like ? Please paste.

Comment: [Your code works btw](http://jsfiddle.net/4k2qfn67/)

Comment: I added some clarification above (html tag info, html link calling the function, where the javascript it, etc). Also, I know the code "works"... just want the error gone before I add other things to the page.

Comment: "The only "<" that is used is to designate the javascript"

Are you sure? There aren't any `<html>`, `<body>`, etc. tags in the file? If the error is coming up but the JS works, its probably not a problem with the JS tag. Did the error give you a line number, and if so, whats on that line?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is valid if it's in an HTML document. However if it's in a JavaScript file (eg: `file.js`) then you don't need to include the `<script>` tag.

The `<script>` tag is used in HTML documents to include JavaScript code within HTML.

The leading character of the `<script>` tag (`<`) is confusing the JavaScript parser, and causing your error.

Comment: This code is embedded at the top of my page. Not inside an external javascript file.

Comment: @Jabbamonkey How did you embed the code on the top of the page inside <script> when it is in file.js ?

Comment: It is NOT in a js file. The <script> tag is in the html file.

Comment: @Jabbamonkey you will have to show more code for us to understand and help you. Perhaps set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and post the link here.